# Flutter/Dart Compare multiple Lists and generate list with elements containd in all given lists

Tags: flutter, dart

So here is my problem:
let's say we have two or more lists

```
List<SomeModel> one = [SomeModel, SomeModel, SomeModel],
List<SomeModel> two = [SomeModel, SomeModel, SomeModel, SomeModel, SomeModel, SomeModel]
```

what I want to do is compare these two/or more lists and make a new List
containing only those elements that exist in every list.

```
List<Fruits> one = [Banana, Apple, Cherry];
List<Fruits> two = [Cherry, Blueberry, Apple, Mango, Pineapple, Pear];
List<Fruits> three = [Cherry, Apple, Mango, Pineapple, Pear, Banana];

List<Fruits> getMatchingList(){
  do something...

  List<Fruits> matchingFruits = [Cherry, Apple];
  return matchingFruits
}
```

I literally have no idea how to do this, especially with larger lists or with lists of unknown content.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of lists is fixed you can just use the where function to filter items:

```
List<SomeModel> filteredList = one.where(item => two.contains(item))
     .where(item => three.contains(item)).toList();
```

So your method will be:

```
List<Fruits> getMatchingList(List<Fruits> one, List<Fruits> two, List<Fruits> three){
   return one.where(item => two.contains(item))
            .where(item => three.contains(item))
            .toList();
}
```

If you need an increasing number of lists to be processed, on the other side, just use:

```
List<Fruits> getMatchingList(List<List<Fruits>> listsToAnalyze){
   Map<Fruits,integer> fruitCounter = new Map();
   //expand is a method that flattern a list of lists in a single list
   listsToAnalyze.expand(element => element).toList().forEach(element => {
    //if the element exists, its counter is increased, otherwise is set to 1
    fruitCounter.update(element, (count) => count+1, ()=> 1);
   }
   //remove results with counter < size of the list of lists
   //supposing that an item can appear only once in each list, this means
   //that the value appeared in all lists
   fruitCounter.removeWhere((key,value)=> value<listsToAnalyze.lenght);

   return fruitCounter.keys.toList();
   
}
```

In case an item can appear multiple times in a single list, do not expand the list and keep a `List<Fruit>` to control if an item was already inserted during each cycle on a list. Remember to empty the map at each new list.

```
List<Fruits> getMatchingList(List<List<Fruits>> listsToAnalyze){
       Map<Fruits,integer> fruitCounter = new Map();
       List<Fruits> fruitsInsertedThisRound= new List();
       //cycle on each list alone
       listsToAnalize.forEach(list => {
           fruitsInsertedThisRound.clear(); //ensure that the list is empty at each cycle
           list.forEach(el => {
           //if the element exists, its counter is increased, otherwise is set to 1
            if(!fruitsInsertedThisRound.contains(el){
              //fruit still not inserted this round
              fruitCounter.update(el, (count) => count+1, ()=> 1);
              fruitsInsertedThisRound.add(el); //add the element to the list of inserted fruits
            }
         }
       }

       //remove results with counter < size of the list of lists
       //this means that the value appeared in all lists
       fruitCounter.removeWhere((key,value)=> value<listsToAnalyze.lenght);

       return fruitCounter.keys.toList();
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge both the list by removing duplicate

**As Single Line**

```
a.addAll(b.takeWhile((item)=> !a.contains(item)));
```

**by looping**

```
for(var item in a){
 if(!b.contains(item)){
  b.add(item);
 }
}
```